# iPhone: UIImagePickerController Randomly Fails to Take Picture

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I use a UIPickerViewController to take picture. It works 80% but seemingly at random it fails to take a picture. In tracing the code I found out that it occasionally goes to

```
-PinRecordNewTableViewController:viewDidUnload.
```

That is where it fails because it set nil to all ivars.

```
@interface PinRecordNewTableViewController : UITableViewController {
}
... 
@implementation PinRecordNewTableViewController
...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
...
        PinRecordNewPicture *pinRecordNewPicture = [[PinRecordNewPicture alloc] initWithNibName:@"PinRecordNewPicture" bundle:nil];
        pinRecordNewPicture.delegate = self;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:pinRecordNewPicture animated:YES];    
        [pinRecordNewPicture release];  
...             
}
@interface PinRecordNewPicture : UIViewController 
...
@implementation PinRecordNewPicture
...
- (void)picturePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)theSource {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = theSource;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

[picker release];
}

- (IBAction) takePicture:(id)sender {

UIImagePickerControllerSourceType source = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:source]) {

       [self picturePicker:source];

    }
```

What did I do wrong? Did I miss something that causes it to behave "randomly"?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The problem is most likely in `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` or  `imagePickerControllerDidCancel:` You should post that code to your answer. Also, more description would help. What behavior to you see when it fails to take a picture? Does it act like it did but you have no image stored? Does the picker controller view never show up? Details are important.

Answer (score 0):

If it called `viewDidUnload`, then it is very likely that your app is running out of memory.  This could be a problem, or just the result of editing large images in phone.

Comment: I just take a regular picture. Will it help if I set "picker.allowsEditing = NO;" ?

Comment: Yes, almost certainly, unless you have a bad leak somewhere else.

Comment: I have just run XCode -> Run -> Run With Performance Tool -> Leaks. It says that I have a leak on the following code specifically on line "UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];".

But I don't understand why.

Do I do something wrong?

- (void)picturePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)theSource {
 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.sourceType = theSource;
 picker.allowsEditing = NO;
 
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
 
 [picker release];
}

Comment: You alloc then release in the same method - so there's no leak.  Instruments sometimes can't tell, and sometimes gets it wrong.

Comment: "UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera hogging up memory" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565886/uiimagepickercontrollersourcetypecamera-hogging-up-memory - explains my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to take multiple pictures, save the current one to the Documents area of the app.  It frees up the memory. This way, the memory warning can be avoided.

If ViewDidUnload is being called, you might think about saving the relevant state of the app in didReceiveMemoryWarning and restoring it in viewDidLoad.  This is done using NSUserDefaults class