# Does a faster than the native UIImageJPEGRepresentation() function exist?

Tags: ios, uikit, jpeg

Are there any other libraries that allow a faster jpg conversion from an UIImage to NSData than the native `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` ?

Another question, what's in a `UIImage`?

Comment: One question per question please. And the 1st answer is "no".

Comment: Actual image data of an `UIImage` is based either on `CIImage` or `CGImage` - depending on how the `UIImage` was initialized. Everything is in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW41).

Comment: You can check this answer for a faster way of encoding.  He says "same or faster". http://stackoverflow.com/a/15858955/1671729