# exif image rotation issue using carrierwave and rmagick to upload to s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, exif, rmagick

I've got a photo upload feature in my rails app. The app uploads direct to s3 through carrierwave via rmagick and fog. The issue I am having is when a photo is uploaded via mobile through the "take a photo option" in portrait (note this is with iphone but I believe android has the same issue). Once uploaded the image appears fine on mobile, however when viewed on desktop the image appears rotated 90 degrees.

Through my research it looks to be an issue with exif. This [stackoverflow responder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051177/2066855) outlines 2 potential solutions. This [gist](https://gist.github.com/jcsrb/1510601) also looks promising as well.

So far I have found a few solutions posted but none have worked. Ideally I would like the photo to be saved to s3 as a portrait, then just display the image as is.

Any suggestions are well appreciated.

Below is my code

## app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  # Include the Sprockets helpers for Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
  include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :fix_exif_rotation
  process :set_content_type


  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fill: [200, 200]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg png)
  end


  def fix_exif_rotation #this is my attempted solution
    manipulate! do |img|
      img = img.auto_orient!
    end
  end


end
```

## app/models/s3_image.rb

```
class S3Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :name, :user_id
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  belongs_to :user


  def image_name
    File.basename(image.path || image.filename) if image
  end


  class ImageWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform(id, key)
      s3_image = S3Image.find(id)
      s3_image.key = key
      s3_image.remote_image_url = s3_image.image.direct_fog_url(with_path: true)
      s3_image.save!
      s3_image.update_column(:image_processed, true)
    end
  end
end
```

## config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: "AWS",
    aws_access_key_id: " ... ",
    aws_secret_access_key: " ... "
  }
  config.fog_directory = " ... "
end
```

btw I used this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3) as a guide for setting up my s3 upload.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well I got this working using fog instead or carrierwave_direct.

Below is the code that ended up working for me:

app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

   include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
   include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

   storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end


  def fix_exif_rotation #this is my attempted solution
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.tap(&:auto_orient)
    end
  end

  process :fix_exif_rotation
end
```

app/models/s3_image.rb

```
class S3Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :name, :user_id, :image_cache
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  belongs_to :user
end
```

initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: "AWS",
    aws_access_key_id: " ... ",
    aws_secret_access_key: " ... ",
    region: 'us-west-2'
  }
  config.fog_directory = " ... "
end
```

Comment: @JonathanAllard the `manipulate!` block wants an image, but `image.auto_orient` returns an empty string. `image.tap(&:auto_orient)` roughly corresponds to `image.auto_orient ; image`.

Comment: Worked for me only when using `img.tap(&:auto_orient!)` (note the bang!). But I am also using  `CarrierWave::RMagick` instead of  `CarrierWave::MiniMagick`

Comment: Sumeet's solution only works for the versions. The uploaded original image is still rotated.

This solution from @lando2319 works for both the original image and the thumbnails.

Comment: I needed to add the bang as well `img.tap(&:auto_orient!)`. Thanks for the `fix_exif_rotation` method.

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem and fixed it with an approach nearly identical to yours.

```
# In the uploader:
def auto_orient
  manipulate! do |img|
    img = img.auto_orient
  end
end
```

(Note that I am not calling `auto_orient!` - just `auto_orient`, without the *bang*.)

Then I have `process :auto_orient` as the first line of any `version` I create. For example:

```
version :square do
  process :auto_orient
  process :resize_to_fill => [600, 600]
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately this didn't fix my issue.

Comment: I added this to my versions then recreated the versions and it has fixed the sideways image issues. So far I've only tested it with images uploaded via safari on ios 7. hopefully it works across the board.  thanks.

Answer (score 6):

My solution (quite similar to Sumeet) :

```
# painting_uploader.rb
process :right_orientation
def right_orientation
  manipulate! do |img|
    img.auto_orient
    img
  end
end
```

It's really important to return an image. Otherwise, you'll get an

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `write' for "":String):
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me, whereas @Sumeet's did not, despite how similar. Also, thanks for the tip about the need to *return an image*. For the record, I had a similar error `NoMethodError (undefined method 'destroy!' for "":String)`.

Answer (score 2):

[Lando2319's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650530/1397994) was not working for me.

I am using RMagick.

I managed to make ImageMagick apply the correct orientation (and to reset the EXIF rotation data in order to avoid a double rotation by the viewer) by using :

```
def fix_exif_rotation # put this before any other process in the Carrierwave uploader

manipulate! do |img|
  img.tap(&:auto_orient!)
end
```

The difference between my solution & Lando's is the bang (!). In my case it was absolutely necessary.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue using RMagick with iPhone images which got fixed 
as I call it at the start of my `name_uploaded.rb` file 
after 
 `include CarrierWave::ImageRounder`
like this 
  `process :fix_exif_rotation`