# Carrierwave undefined metho auto_orient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rmagick

I've been trying to use RMagick auto_orient method to fix mobile uploads. Currently they are rotated 90 degrees. My uploader file currently looks like this.

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

include CarrierWave::RMagick

storage :fog
def root
  Rails.root.join 'public/'
end
include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
process :set_content_type

def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

process :resize_to_fill => [200, 200]

version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50]
end

process :auto_orient

def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end

end
```

This is giving me an error

`undefined local variable or method auto_orient for AvatarUploader:Class (NameError)`

I've tried several solutions, 
[exif image rotation issue using carrierwave and rmagick to upload to s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519160/exif-image-rotation-issue-using-carrierwave-and-rmagick-to-upload-to-s3), https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/issues/68
but no dice.

Anyone got a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following:

```
def auto_orient
  manipulate! do |img|
    img.auto_orient!
  end
end
```

As it stands now, the `auto_orient` process you're referencing doesn't exist in the context, hence the error.

Edit: according to the imagemagick github link you posted, `auto_orient!` might be broken. You could then use `auto_orient` instead in a similar way (it just creates a new image instead of modifying the one passed to the method). Refer to the links you posted for possible solutions using the `auto_orient` method.

Comment: Thank you. Been banging my head off the wall. I thought I'd tried your method but I obviously made a mistake. I was just about to comment that the bang method had been removed but you beat me to it :) Thank you