# Process `auto_orient` with Cloudinary upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave, cloudinary, minimagick

I had a regular file upload that I now changed to using Cloudinary.

Upon upload I did the following to prevent orientation glitches when uploading images from a mobile device (See [exif image rotation issue using carrierwave and rmagick to upload to s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519160/exif-image-rotation-issue-using-carrierwave-and-rmagick-to-upload-to-s3) for details):

```
process :rotate
process :store_dimensions

def rotate
  manipulate! do |image|
    image.tap(&:auto_orient)
  end
end

def store_dimensions
  # This does not work with cloudinary #18

  if file && model
    model.width, model.height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(file.file)[:dimensions]
  end
end
```

Neither rotation nor storing the dimensions work, since I switched to cloudinary.

Now Cloudinary has [an official tutuorial](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202519822-How-to-retrieve-image-dimensions-when-uploading-to-Cloudinary-using-CarrierWave-) that shows how to do this but it simply does not work and other people seem to have the same issue and neither of the provided options worked for me:

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working using a variation of the first option:

```
  after_save :update_dimensions

  def update_dimensions
    if self.image != nil && self.image.metadata.present?
      width = self.image.metadata["width"]
      height = self.image.metadata["height"]

      self.update_column(:width, width)
      self.update_column(:height, height)

    end
  end
```

**Important**: since we're inside a `after_save` callback here it's crucial to use `update_column` so that we don't trigger another callback and end up in an infinite loop.

**Fix for the provided solution**:

`self.image.present?` returned `false` but `self.image != nil` returend `true`.