# Rails | Carrierwave rotates image 90 degrees

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am uploading images to s3 using `fog` and `carrierwave`. I am using the below code for profile picture:

```
version :listpic do
     process :resize_to_fill_modfied => [100, 100] 
   end

    version :usershow do
     process :resize_to_fill_modfied => [225, 225] #user profile pic kullanılıyor
   end

   def resize_to_fill_modfied(width, height, gravity=::Magick::CenterGravity)
      manipulate! do |img|
        img.crop_resized!(width, height, gravity) unless (img.columns <= width && img.rows <= height)
        img = yield(img) if block_given?
        img
      end
    end
```

The problem is, when I try to upload an image 193x193 it rotates to 90 degrees to left. Why is that?

**EDIT**

When I try to upload 250x250 it again rotates.

Comment: have you trued with the option mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519160/exif-image-rotation-issue-using-carrierwave-and-rmagick-to-upload-to-s3 ?

Comment: I very recently had this same issue. I'm assuming these images were taken with a smartphone. I'm not using carrierwave, but I used `auto_orient` from graphicsmagick to rotate the image correctly. There was one caveat, which is that auto_orient doesn't remove the EXIF that is causing the rotation in the first place, so I had to use auto_orient and *then* strip EXIF data.

Comment: You can use the tool at http://metapicz.com/ to see what exif data your image has. You'll see exactly why it's being rotated

Comment: I have tried all the solutions but none working.

Answer (score 2):

I see from the comments on the question that you've "tried all the solutions," but have you installed MiniMagick?

```
# Add this in your Gemfile after CarrierWave and Fog:
gem 'mini_magick'
# then run `bundle install`
```

Once you've done that, try again with this in the uploader:

```
def fix_exif_rotation 
  manipulate! do |img|
    img.tap(&:auto_orient)
  end
end
```

Comment: But I use RMagick, can I do the same thing with RMagick?

Comment: MiniMagick is an alternative for RMagick.
It looks like you should be able to do something similar with RMagick, but I can only speak to that what I posted above works for me with MiniMagick.

https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#auto_orient