# Make UIImagePickerViewController No rotate

Tags: iphone

anybody know how to fix the orientation when use UIImagePickerViewController?
IT seems, it always rotate when you rotate iPhone 
I want to take a picture only one orientation. so I can crop some place of the image

If it's not fixed. I need consider four situations 
every orientation I need set the crop frame, it crashed me .

Comment: `UIImagePickerViewController` does not support orientations itself. This means default controls don't change its positions when you rotate device. However, the `UIImage` object returned by `UIImagePickerViewController`'s delegate holds the orientation which it has been taken with. Maybe this answer will help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19640989/1492173)