# orientation of image in imageview is shifted 90 left in device

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

i am selecting image from imagepickercontroller and diplaying in an imageview.however for images taken from the camera ,they always appear 90 left in the device.for the images i take in the simulator they have the correct orientation.how to correct this.should i specify any orientation for images

Comment: Try the code in the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538041/uiimagepickercontroller-camera-preview-is-portrait-in-landscape-app/538064#538064

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue myself. The way I solved it was to check the images orientation and then rotate it if it was supposed to be landscape.

The code I used was:

```
float orientation = [[myPhotoAsset valueForProperty:@"ALAssetPropertyOrientation"] floatValue];

if (orientation == 3)
    photo = [self CGImageRotatedByAngle:photo angle:-90];
```

Cheers

Comment: but i am not using the alassets frmwrk.i am using the uiimagepickercontroller.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but finally I solved it with the following code:

UIImage*Image=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]];