# How to apply cameraViewTransform to a UIImagePickerController originalImage

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uiimagepickercontroller, transform

I made my custom UIImagePickerController camera controls (flash, front/rear, zoom, takepicture and others).

My issue is related to zooming.
By clicking plus and minus buttons, I change the imagePicker.cameraViewTransform with a scale. All right here.

When the user pick the photos, in the delegate method didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo, I get the originalImage.
That UIImage, obviously, does not have the transform applied.

My question is:
HOW DO I GET THE IMAGE SCALED (BY APPLYING THAT TRANSFORM, WHICH I HAVE) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cameraViewTransform is just for the (live)image being shown but not the image captured. Hence that wont be reflected on the image captured.

In order to Scale (Zoom in/out ) the captured image you need to work on the captured image (remember the scale applied while taking picture). As a matter of fact you need to scale and rotate the obtained image for orientation specific issues :

see the following stackoverflow link :
[UIImagePickerController camera preview is portrait in landscape app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538041/uiimagepickercontroller-camera-preview-is-portrait-in-landscape-app)

Comment: @Fabio B. Please update if the suggestions helps. That helps us. Not being responsive doesn't help ...