# UIImagePickerController - SourceType Camera - Allow taking photo only portrait orientation

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to prevent user from taking photo at the landscape orientation and allow only portrait. Is there a way you know to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538041/uiimagepickercontroller-camera-preview-is-portrait-in-landscape-app

Answer (score 1):

There are different things to consider here:

1) you want the camera button not to change for Landscape orientation (to indicate Portrait orientation only).You can achieve this by having custom controls and having your own Camera Control Bar.

camController.showsCameraControls = NO; // this will disable the default controls
camController.cameraOverlayView = controlsView; // this view shows the required camera button in portrait only way.

2) Modifying the image data after capture

This is a tedious thing (already mentioned in many blogposts/stackoverflow)

[UIImagePickerController camera preview is portrait in landscape app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538041/uiimagepickercontroller-camera-preview-is-portrait-in-landscape-app)

Now rotate your image by 90 degrees (or 270 deg based on orientation) to make it look portrait.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try your recommendation.

Comment: please try and let me know if it addresses your issue.

Comment: @crazywood, any luck with my suggestion ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, i have tried to use camera control with custom camera control, but taken photo size has changed according to device orientation. So I'm not able to prevent user from taking photo at the landscape orientation and i have modified the image differently according to the orientation of the taken photo.

Comment: If you take image in Landscape orientation and rotate the image, doesnt it address the issue for you ?

Comment: Yes, i did something like you said. But i cannot prevent user from taking photo at the landscape. And i made different actions according to the orientation of the taken image.