# Saving a photo based on the device orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

The following code gives me a photo in portrait mode irrespective of the orientation. How do I ensure the photo respects the current orientation?

```
-(void) TakePhotoWithCamera
{
    [self startCameraPickerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];
}

 - (BOOL)startCameraPickerFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller usingDelegate:(id<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>)delegateObject  
{  
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
        picker.delegate = self;
        [controller presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];   
    }

    return YES;  
}  

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage * img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
    [self useImage:img];
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)useImage:(UIImage *)theImage {
    NSData *addImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(theImage);
    // Here we return the Image
}
```

My aplication is in portrait mode. if I select the image from gallery or with camera , I am getting the image like Tiles with above coding.

Comment: Have you looked at [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315251/how-to-rotate-a-uiimage-90-degrees)? You can shift the image's orientation based on the current orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Image taken from your iPhone Camera will have orientation`(UIImageOrientation)` information (EXIF info). This tells exactly in what orientation the image is. If the Viewer is capable of understanding this info , it will display them properly else you will see the images as it is (I guess Safari doesn't respect the orientation, just compare opening with safari).

Now, There is a (pseudo) standard procedure followed after image capture to make it default orientation (UIImageOrientationUp) and internally rotating the actual image - which makes the image viewable on any viewer.

please check the following post and use the scaleAndRotate function. This shall address your issue.
[UIImagePickerController camera preview is portrait in landscape app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538041/uiimagepickercontroller-camera-preview-is-portrait-in-landscape-app).

Also have a look at my answer on related question (how do you make it Portrait only or Landscape only) , it might help you as well
[UIImagePickerController - SourceType Camera - Allow taking photo only portrait orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203428/uiimagepickercontroller-sourcetype-camera-allow-taking-photo-only-portrait-or/6225183#6225183)