# Image inside camera in iPad 2 appears rotated 90 degrees clockwise

Tags: camera, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller, ipad-2

I have an app that works on landscape, already in the store, and decided to add a camera for a certain new feature in my next update.

The camera works perfect in my iPhone 3G and iPod 4S ( i have an ipad, but it doesn't has a camera), but one of my testers with an ipad 2 reported that the image inside the camera appears rotated 90 degrees in clockwise direction ( same for the small camera icon in the button). Even if the user rotates the ipad 2 the image always mantains that rotation. Once the picture is taken it appears it's saved correct position.

- Before giving more details, any idea of why i situation like this can
  happen ? ( that could help me to trace the problem). I just didn't
  know it was possible to rotate the preview image inside the camera !, and i'm currently clueless about what can cause to produce this behavior.
- It could be something related to my view controller ?. I'm returning NO for 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait' and 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown'. YES for 'UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft' and 'UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'. If understand correctly it's as it should be.
- The camera implementation is pretty straightfoward, just an
  UIImagePickerController. After creating it, i'm adding it as subview
  to an specific uiview that happens to be rotated 90 degrees Clockwise
  ( could this be the issue ?, but if it is, why it works correctly in
  my other devices with camera ?!). I tried to apply a transformation (
  [picker view].transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);) but
  it had no effect.

By the time being i don't have an ipad 2 ( it's on it's way), but in the meantime i would like to solve the issue, or at least try to understand why it could be happening.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers !

Here's the code for the view controller method where i handle the rotation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
                if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
            {
                return YES; 
            }
            else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
            {
                return YES; 
            }
            else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
            {
                return NO;
            }
                else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
            {
                return NO;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I'm also facing same kind of issue.

Comment: i am also facing the same problem :(

Comment: (Re-posting this comment from another thread)
We faced the same problem. We used the solution from Alex, given here ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538041/uiimagepickercontroller-camera-preview-is-portrait-in-landscape-app

Comment: See my answer here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600613/ios-image-orientation-has-strange-behavior/10602363#10602363  I got from apple support