# For some reason when uploading an image to Facebook after taking a picture it rotates image by 90 degrees

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, image, uiimagepickercontroller

The following code is the method that I use to take picture with and then send to Facebook using share kit. Problem is this causes images to be sent with a 90 degree rotation.The reason I know this is the code that is responsible for this is because if I upload an image from the iPhone gallery the image gets shared to Facebook normally.

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
    [imagePickerController setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}
// image picker needs a delegate,
[imagePickerController setDelegate:self];
// Place image picker on the screen
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default orientation of a `UIImagePickerController` is landscape I believe. Therefore, you need to hack around with the image you obtain after taking the picture. There are many ways to do this - check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/538041/1415949). There are several methods discussed there to normalize the orientation.

Comment: Thanks,by any chance do you know the best way I can pass my method into - (UIImage *)scaleAndRotateImage:(UIImage *)image {

Comment: In the `imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method, you grab the UIImage. Then once you have that image call the `scaleAndRotateImage:` method. You'll get a new image from that, and then you can just upload it to Facebook!