# Image roates after CIFilter applied

Tags: swift, cifilter, ciimage

I'm applying a CIFilter to an image but it gets rotated after the filter is applied. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657131/uiimage-sideway-after-converting-it-from-ciimage) in objective-c, how could I do this in swift? My code is below.

```
let originalImage = CIImage(image: cameraStill.image)

var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffect"+x)
filter.setDefaults()
filter.setValue(originalImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

var outputImage = filter.outputImage
var newImage = UIImage(CIImage: outputImage)
v.setImage(newImage, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image auto-rotates after using CIFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833285/image-auto-rotates-after-using-cifilter)

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked fine for me:

```
    var image = UIImage(named: "Turtle")
    let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")
    filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(1.5, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
    let newImage = UIImage(CIImage: filter.outputImage)
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: newImage)
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Let me know how you go.

Comment: Are you using a square image? The problem happens with portrait images